# AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

i started learning python a few days ago and wanted to make a simple class.
A friend of mine, who is well known in Python, send me these asserts to test my program.
When running the program, i get this error:
"AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'name'"
When i run the code through a python visualizer (https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)
I can see the program actualy creating the constructor and the class but somehow it doesnt find the attribute "name" when going through the assert.

```
class Student:
    
    def __init__(self, name, uci_name, semester):
        self.name = name
        self.uci_name = uci_name
        self.semester = semester
    
    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
    def get_uci_name(self) -> str:
        return self.uci_name
    
    def get_semester(self) -> int:
        return self.semester
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} [{self.uci_name}] in Semester {self.semester}"

student_tom = Student("Tom", "tom55", 3)
    
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "name"), property)
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "uci_name"), property)
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "semester"), property)
```

Comment: `getattr(Student, "name")` is trying to access the `name` attribute on the _class_. It's **not** a property, hence doesn't exist.

Comment: In your `getattr` calls, replace `Student` with `student_tom`.

Comment: It looks like you were supposed to write those fields as properties.

Answer (score 0):

**First off**: the class `Student` doesn't itself have the attributes you are checking for here, they are only set in `__init__`, which like the name alludes to, is called at initialization of an instance (what is `self` really? The instance!). However, as a side note, change your `getattr` strings to the method names and you will see that you **won't** get any `AttributeError`, since those are indeed attributes of the class. It's just that whatever's inside the `__init__` isn't, because how could it? So the solution to this problem is to check your instance `student_tom` instead of the class itself, because then those attributes have actually been set.

**Secondly**: Once you change it to check the instance, you will get an `AssertionError` instead (progress!). This means that the attributes you are checking are not **properties**, which is a special type of method (read: decorator) unique to python that removes the need for getters, which is why you will almost never see traditional getters (or setters, which are built-on in a similar fashion) in pythonic code. Mandatory Raymond Hettinger: https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg?t=2213